# How to send emails in Java using threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, email

How to send emails using threads? I write the following code, but it doesn't work. It doesn't throw any exception, but I don't receive the email too. If I don't use the threads, the code works properly. What's the problem?

```
    final String username = "admin@gmail.com";
    final String password = "admin";

    new Thread(()-> {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.prot", "465");

        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
                new Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {

                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                }
        );
        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(username));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipient));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setText(text);
            Transport.send(message);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something is wrong!");
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: you are not printing exceptions, do `e.printStackTrace();`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It looks like you may need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please [edit] your question to be more specific with what help you need.

Comment: Is this a Spring Boot or Spring application?